# Force asynchronous function to be synchronous without async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to force an asynchronous function to run synchronously. My situation is really complicated so I'll try to explain.

I am developing a Ionic application that communicates with a server.

- In this application, I am charging an html page generated by a webservice, creating a new component with createComponent, and compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync.
- In this html sent by webservice, there are some script tags. these scripts are custom javascript made by other persons, but they use functions created by us. As an example, we made a fonction "createdByUs". And other persons can make custom javascript with it (example below).
- The "createdByUs" function were created before the Ionic application, and many persons have used it. but It has another behavior in ionic, and that behavior is asynchronous, event if the function was synchronous before.
- Now I have to adapt this function for the ionic application and, since the custom scripts have been created before, I must edit the "createdByUs". The code works well, it's juste that it is asynchronous, so the rest of the custom code executes before the end of "createdByUs"

```
  <!-- our function -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    inIonic = true;
    function createdByUs(){
        if(inIonic){
            new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('Promise is created and consumed');
                resolve('Promise is created and consumed');
              }, 5000);
            });
        }else{
            console.log("nice synchronous code");
        }   
    }
  </script>

  <!-- custom functions made by other persons I can not modify -->
  <script type="text/javascript" id="customScript">
    createdByUs();
    console.log("other code that must wait for createdByUs");
  </script>
```

Since I cannot modify the custom script, I cannot simple put "cratedbyus" as async and use await for it everywere. is there a solution for my problem ?

--- EDIT 
Some precisions about the project :
It's a sort of "page editor", we provide a graphic interface, and an area where people can define custom scripts. I am working on an application that would display these pages and were the scripts would work. but some functions don't work in Ionic, so I have to redefine them. 
To run the ionic code, I call an event in createdByUs that is received in ionic. It works well, excepts the event is asynchronous, and in addition, it adds html elements in an ngfor, and ionic doesn't create the elements immediately when you modify you array source of ngfor, so the generation of html in ngfor is asynchronous too. it's endless...

Comment: You could return the Promise and use `Promise.then(() => { ... })`

Comment: If you return the promise, you'd have to modify how the function is utilized elsewhere (.then() etc...). Which she says cannot be done...

Comment: I would have to put all the next code (in my example, the "console.log("other code that must wait for createdByUs");") in this then, and that everytime the function is called

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: I couldn't because the custom code could contain anyhting, if I wrap all the custom code in "then" and add a "});" at the end, some functions defined in custom script would be unreachable before the call of "cretedByUs"

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't do that. If you could do that, it would create various problems (e.g. the `setTimeout` callback could not run to actually resolve the promise, as the thread would be blocked waiting on the promise), therefore it cannot be done in any way, and it won't be possible in the future.

---

You might say

*But why isn't there  a way, that behaves similar to `await` inside of non async functions, so that the running execution context gets stored, removed from the stack, and then later resumes when the promise resolves?*.

Well for sure one could do that, but that would break the *run to completion guarantee* of functions, in other words it would make every piece of code non deterministic, and thats generally a bad thing (in other words: concurrent modifications, out of order execution etc.).

*But there is that "global `await` proposal" that allows to `await` on the top level, outside of `async` functions?*

Yes, but that is restricted onto the top level, also the execution order is still deterministic (all required modules finish before the module depending on it gets run).

Comment: Well, I have no choice :,(

Comment: What is the actual asynchronous task that has to be run before the custom scripts code runs?

Comment: I made an edit on the post that details more what i'm trying to do now, and more about the project itself and why I have not really other choice that making my function synchronous

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bit of a hack.

Run the async function as is but return the promise. Then once the promise resolves, then you load the other script.

```
myPromise.then(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = 'path/to/otherScript'
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script)
})
```

Comment: That would work if I would sure the "createdByUs" function were before the rest, but in the custom script people can call it several times, make function that calls it...

Comment: Then another solution would be to change the descriptor of the original function. Or use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Could I redefine an asynchronous method to a synchronous one with a Proxy ?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now. The code that follows the `createdByUs` is unknown. There's no clean way of doing what you want.

Comment: Well I'm actually searching for a way, it doesn't have to be clean (you can't imagine how I would like to, but since I cannot modify the "customscript"...)

Comment: It sounds like you're working on plugin/library/framework that others ingest. So if you have no way of knowing or modifying their code then this is a breaking change and must be included in a major version update, if you're following semver semantics.

Comment: I made an edit with some precisions about the project, you're not far from the truth ^^'

Comment: I'll just precise that people have a "maintenance agreement", so their code must work in the ionic application, I sadly cannot simply say "well, ahem, it won't work on the mobile version héhé =D"